# Toc, Bibliography, Indexes and dots

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

I have to add to the ToC the Bibliography and the Indexes (e. g., the Author index) in such a way that they have the same style of a Chapter without the Chapter number.

In particular, I need to add dots and page numbers of the Bibliography and the Indexes in the ToC.

The result I want to get is something like this

> BIBLIOGRAPHY............................................3
>
> AUTHOR INDEX...........................................42

What is the easiest way to do it?

**Additional Notes**

I have used imakeidx for the indexes.

This is the first part of the tex files I have to modify.

> ```
>            \documentclass[twoside,openright, titlepage,numbers=noenddot, headinclude, %openany openright oneside twoside
>             footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty, abstractoff, 
>             BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,%11pt,a4paper,
>             ngerman,american,
>     % bibliography=totoc
>             ]{scrreprt}
> ```

This is what I can get for the moment

[image]

The Bibliography appears since I've used

> \usepackage[nottoc, chapter]{tocbibind}

Comment: Hi and welcome, depends on the class and/or the used packages. If you are using a KOMA-class have a look at `bibliography` to toc and the related options.

Comment: The class is scrreprt. I added this information in the question. I search a long but I couldn't find anything, unfortunately.

Comment: `\KOMAoption{bibliography}{totoc}\KOMAoption{index}{totoc}`

Comment: btw: one of the options i just mentioned is uncommented in your code snippet. Go on an adventure and try testing a bit ;-) Nothing will explode by removing the comment char there.

Comment: @Johannes_B thanks for your help, but I know how to add indexes and Bibliography to ToC. The real problem is that they appear just as headers without the dots and the page number and with the number of the chapter.

Comment: Those are chapters by default and are treated that way. You could use them as section headings.  If you see other chapters with leaders, some package might have taken control (maybe in an incompatible way). Please inform us about that in form of a minimal working example. EDIT: Ah, package `tocbibind`. It whacks KOMA-functionality dead and uses a stone instead.

Comment: If I remove tocbibind package and uncomment "bibliography=totoc" the result is the same.

Comment: I don't know how other chapters in you document look like. By default, KOMA does *not* put leaders in there. So you are doing something non-standard. Problem is, i don't know what and so rely on your information in form of a [compilable test case])http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html).

Comment: I find out part of the problem. I have added \addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}} this line because I do not wanted it for chapters (with sections). Do you think there is a way to make the things works as I like them?

Comment: `titlesec` is another extension for the standard classes that just beats KOMA numb. You should get a respective warning.

Comment: Dear @Johannes_B I think I've solved all my problems. Since in the tex file I just make use of chapters and sections, I've make the Bibliography a ``Part'' which resemble a chapter. Thanks for the talk!

Comment: I just saw your other qyestion, that would have answered all i was asking above? Why didn't you post a simple link?

Comment: Because I first find out how to solve the problem in this question and then I asked to myself (and also posted) the other one.

Comment: Is there any news here?

Comment: As I said in a previous comment I solved my problems

Comment: Do you mind providing an answer that might help other users with a similar problem?

Comment: Well, It was not a real solution to the problem; I've just putted things in some form I like it, manually making the bibliography as a "part". Can this be still an answer?

Comment: If it helped you, it is an answer. But please mention, that this was a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Workaround**

I solved everything in a manual way: I've just created a ``part'' which resembles the bibliography. Anyway this works easy only if you do not have many references and do not need to change often the document.